# How does Linux Expect script work?

Tags: linux, expect

I ever tried to input password by I/O redirection like `echo <password> | ssh <user>@<host>`, but it didn't work of course. Then I got that ssh actually reads password directly from /dev/tty instead of STDIN, so I/O redirection doesn't work for it.

As far as I know, Expect script is the standard way for this kind of job. I'm curious about how Expect works? I guess it runs the target program in a child process, and it changes the /dev/tty of the child process to refer to another place, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

It uses something called a pseudo-TTY which looks to the called program like a TTY, but allows for programmed control. See e.g. [Don Libes' *Exploring Expect* p498f](http://books.google.fi/books?id=BJpkh3RdG_UC&pg=PA498&lpg=PA498&dq=expect+pty&source=bl&ots=PoYlwZubSy&sig=oTFVpHBBCzUjPQpX6YdHl7Haq5k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AtYOU5TdEMPD4gSGqIHADQ&redir_esc=y)